# $\lim \inf \lambda (a_n)=\lambda \lim \inf (a_n)$ for bounded below sequence or function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Does anyone have a proof for following expression?

$\lim \inf \lambda (a_n)=\lambda \lim \inf  (a_n)$ for $\lambda>0$

Is it necessary to proof with sub-sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the infimum first.

Let $L = \inf \lambda a_n$ and  $J = \inf a_n$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $L+ \epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $\{\lambda a_n\}$, so  there exists an index $n$ with $\lambda a_n \le L + \epsilon$. Since $\lambda > 0$ if follows that $\lambda J \le \lambda a_n < L + \epsilon$. Now let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ to conclude $\lambda J \le L$. The proof that $L \le \lambda J$ is nearly identical.

Now define sequences $$b_n = \inf_{k \ge n} \lambda a_k \quad \text{and} \quad c_n = \inf_{k \ge n} a_k$$
so that $b_n \uparrow \liminf \lambda a_n$ and $c_n \uparrow \liminf a_n$.

We just proved that $b_n = \lambda c_n$, so use the limit law to conclude $$\liminf{\lambda a_n} = \lim b_n = \lambda \lim c_n = \lambda \liminf a_n.$$